# spring boot gradle project with multiple modules not creating fat jar properly

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle

I have a spring boot gradle project with multiple modules in it. The parent project (metadata) is just the root folder for child projects and there are 3 child projects (api, security and ui).

1. security is a standalone project that uses spring security. here is its pom

   ```
   dependencies {
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
        compile "com.att.security:csp-cookies:1.0" 
       compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api"
   }
   ```
2. api project uses some of classes from security project so it depends on that

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest") {
           exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
       }
       compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4"
       compile(project(":metadata-security")) 
   }
   ```

   3.finally the UI project is the runnable project that combines everything together.

   ```
       dependencies {
           compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
           compile project(":api:metadata-api-invenio")
           compile(project(":metadata-security"))
       }
   ```

When I do gradle build spring boot gradle plugin generates the fat jar for all 3 projects. Upon extracting the jar file it seems like all the transitive deps from all projects are available in the libs folder inside the fat jar. This is good but for some reason the security project jar file is a fat jar and contains its dependencies inside its lib folder which is not needed. In contrast to that, api project jar is not a fat one and only contains its classes because its jars are already available in the ui fat jar.

Any ideas why security project jar is being created different from api project.

Comment: It sounds like you've applied the Spring Boot plugin to the security module so it's being repackaged into a fat jar. Either remove the plugin from that project or disable repackaging